# Help! I disabled both of my monitors. What can I do?

Tags: monitor

I am new to Ubuntu. I was looking to see if double monitors were supported, and I accidentally disabled both of mine. What can I do? I tried plugging in a third monitor, but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? If nothing needs to be saved, press `ctrl+alt+F1` and then `ctrl+alt+delete`
How did you disable both monitors? Ubuntu will default back to the previous display settings if you do not click "accept."

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use xrandr to turn your monitor back on.
Switch to another terminal with ctl-alt-f1, login and typing xrandr will list your monitors. (assuming xrandr is installed- you might have to sudo apt-get install xrandr)
From there it'll be something like xrandr --output FILL-IN-NAME-HERE   --auto

Hope it works for you